# CSS focus not working when we add target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any possible way to do this with css , i have a `DOM` like this

```css
.nav_bar {
 background: #c30015;
 margin-left: 50px;
 float: left;
}
.nav_bar > ul {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 display: flex;
 border-bottom: thin white solid;
 position:relative;
}
.nav_bar ul li {
 list-style: none;
}
.nav_bar ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 display: block;
 border-right: 1px solid #fff;
 padding: 8px 16px;
}
.nav_bar ul li a:hover {
 background: #e6b3a1;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #c3000f;
}

.nav_bar ul li a:focus , .nav_bar ul li a:active {
 background: #e6b3a1;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #c3000f;
}

.down_nav_bar {
 background: #e6b3a1;
 margin-left: 34px;
 float: left;
 position:absolute !important;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 display:none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.down_nav_bar li {
 list-style: none;
 display:inline-block;
}
.down_nav_bar li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #c3000f;
 display: block;
 padding: 8px 23px 8px 18px;
}
.down_nav_bar li a:link {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.down_nav_bar li a:visited {
 border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.down_nav_bar li a:hover {
 border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.down_nav_bar li a:active {
 border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.down_nav_bar li .active {
 border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
 text-decoration: none;
}
:target {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Post sponsor job</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Applied KOLs</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#target">Purchase and billing</a>
      <ul id="target" class="down_nav_bar">
        <li><a href="#" class="active">Purchase Plan</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">My account</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">Invoice</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">How to pay</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

focus working with all links except the 3rd link , i don't know why this happening, i have added `:visited , :active` also but nothing is worked

Comment: What do you mean the focus is not working? -Now I am on Chrome, and target is working and I can see the colors changes by each tab press

Comment: when you click first button you can see the background changed , second one also, but you click third button , the background dosnt changed

Comment: hope it works fine as kermani said. Which browser you are using?

Comment: can you reproduce it in plunkr?.. third button means 'purchase and billing' or 'Invoice'

Comment: i think may be you don't understand the question. background changes working on hover all menu, but focus not working 3rd menu , click each menu except 3rd menu all change the background

Comment: yes, you click the 3rd one there is a dropdown open, but the 3rd one is not active

Comment: What do you mean not active?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131504/discussion-between-jishnu-v-s-and-sharmila).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve your intended result, by moving your `id="target"` to the anchor which contains `href="#target"` and adding the following styles:

```
#target:target {
  color: #c3000f;
  background-color: #e6b3a1;
}

#target:target + ul {
  display:block;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.nav_bar {
  background: #c30015;
  margin-left: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.nav_bar > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: thin white solid;
  position:relative;
}
.nav_bar ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
.nav_bar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

.nav_bar ul li a:hover,
.nav_bar ul li a:focus,
.nav_bar ul li a:active,
#target:target {
  background: #e6b3a1;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #c3000f;
}

.down_nav_bar {
  background: #e6b3a1;
  margin-left: 34px;
  float: left;
  position:absolute !important;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  display:none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.down_nav_bar li {
  list-style: none;
  display:inline-block;
}
.down_nav_bar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #c3000f;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 23px 8px 18px;
}
.down_nav_bar li a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.down_nav_bar li a:visited {
  border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.down_nav_bar li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.down_nav_bar li a:active {
  border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.down_nav_bar li .active {
  border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#target:target + ul {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Post sponsor job</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Applied KOLs</a> </li>
    <li><a id="target" href="#target">Purchase and billing</a>
      <ul class="down_nav_bar">
        <li><a href="#" class="active">Purchase Plan</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">My account</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">Invoice</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">How to pay</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what i am looking for, Up vote for you are amazing. let me check what happening